# Zipcodes and zones in google maps

Tags: google-maps, zipcode

Is it possible to make zones in google maps, when provided with the zipcodes? 
If it is possible I would really like some links to information about it :)

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by zones?

Comment: Kinda like http://www.usnaviguide.com/areacode.htm where you can see the different area codes on the map.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These is no simple way to accomplish this in Google Maps. You'll have to create your own GPolygons or custom tile layer. The site you noted in your comment has good examples of several different ways to accomplish this.

You can get zip code boundary data [here](http://www.census.gov/geo/www/cob/zt_metadata.html).